# how to add multiple selectors for jquery next?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement jquery next() and prev() functionality so how can i choose the next element whether it's child1 or child2 as next(".child1, .child2") does not work ?

```
$(".child1").next(".child1, .child2").css("background-color":"black")

<style>
.parent {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
</style>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Going prev/next usually implies you are on a current.  It's unclear from what you have provided, what the current element is, and what interaction happens that would invoke the next or previous logic, and what that logic is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make every next element after child1 black then your code's working fine.
But if you're trying to select the first element after `.child1` or `child2` then read the following

You should add the common class to every child node like this

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child2"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child2"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child2"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child1"></div>
  <div class="child child2"></div>
</div>
```

and access it like this.

`$(".child").next().css("background-color", "black")`

it could go like this

`$(".child").next().next()...`

Comment: I feel like it is a bad habit to suggest to people that they should assign multiple copies of the same id to multiple elements. That's a problem down the road waiting to happen.

Comment: SIMPLE YET POWERFUL ANSWER THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax for [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is wrong.

```
.css("background-color":"black")
```

It should be

```
.css("background-color", "black")
```

Secondly, as @Taplar said, your selector is not clear what `this` should be in reference to the .next. What you are actually doing is selecting **every** .child1, then setting the next child1 and child2 to the black css.

Instead, I assume you want to select one child, then set the next. I did a simple example where i use .next to set the css for a clicked child1.

```js
$(".child1").on("click", function(){
  $(this).next(".child1, .child2").css("background-color","black")
});
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.child2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```